# Terminating a running script with subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I am using `subprocess` to execute a python script. I can successfully run the script.

```
import subprocess
import time

proc = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'test.py', ''], shell=True)
proc.communicate()
time.sleep(10)
proc.terminate()
```

test.py

```
import time
while True:
    print("I am inside test.py")
    time.sleep(1)
```

I can see the message `I am inside test.py` printed every second. However, I am not able to terminate the script while it is still running by `proc.terminate()`.

Could someone kindly help me out?

Answer (score 1):

`proc.communicate` waits for the process to finish unless you include a timeout. Your process doesn't exit and you don't have a timeout so `communicate` never returns. You could verify that with a `print` after the call. Instead, add a timeout and catch its exception

```
import subprocess
import time

proc = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'test.py', ''], shell=True)
try:
    proc.communicate(timeout=10)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    proc.terminate()
```

Answer (score 1):

First things first, don't use a list to pass in the arguments for the `subprocess.Popen()` if you're using the `shell = True`!, change the command to `string`, `"python test.py"`.

`Popen.communicate(input=None, timeout=None)` is a blocking class method, it shall Interact with process, and **Wait for process to terminate** and set the returncode attribute.

since your `test.py` running infinite while loop, he will never return !

you have 2 options to timeout the process `proc` that you have spawned:

1. assign the timeout keyword argument in the,e.g. timing the process for 5 seconds, `communicate(timeout=5)` method. If the process `proc` does not terminate after `timeout` seconds, a `TimeoutExpired exception` will be raised. Catching this exception and retrying communication will not lose any output (in your case you dont need the child outputs, but i will mention this in the example below). **ATTENTION** The child process is not killed if the `timeout expires`, so in order to cleanup properly a well-behaved application should kill the child process (`proc`) and finish communication.
2. by using the `poll` method and do the timing by your calling method.

**communicate with timeout**

```
try:
    outs, errs = proc.communicate(timeout=15)
except TimeoutExpired:
    proc.kill()
    outs, errs = proc.communicate()
```

**poll with time.sleep**

```
proc = subprocess.Popen('python test.py', shell=True)
t=10
while proc.poll() is None and t >= 0:
    print('Still sleeping')
    time.sleep(1)
    t -= 1
proc.kill()
```

Comment: Its okay to use a list with `shell=True` ... subprocess will provide any escapes needed and turn it into a string for the shell. Its a convenient way to pass arguments that otherwise would need escaping on your part if you just passed a string.

Comment: Hi @tdelaney, in `communicate with timeout` why we need to communicate again after doing proc.kill() can you please help me